# html code color is light grey on Pydev, how to change it?

Tags: html, eclipse, colors, editor, appearance

I have a problem with Pydev for Eclipse. I have to edit an html file in the Eclipse editor, but the code has a light grey color and I can't find the way to change it.

I have tried the Eclipse 'appearance' menu, but I can't find the right entry! Does someone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a fairly complicated and layered way of determining appearance. I'm not sure specifically about the Pydev variation, but most variations are similar:

Project Menu -> Properties

This should bring up a window with a bunch of drop downs on the left. Which one you want in particular can vary greatly. However, you're looking for an 'Formatter' menu, probably under '(Python) Code Style'. Once you find it, click 'Configure Workspace Settings'. You'll have to create a new active profile and modify it form that menu.

Note that there may be several such 'Formatter' menus and finding the one that handles html is the trick. Good luck!